# +++SOLVED+++ cronjob installed bash script won't execute C program +++see comment+++

Tags: bash, cron, daemon, xterm

Working in Debian 8.5.

The installed cronjob looks like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/MySript.sh
#---------------------------------------------------------------
```

The bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/Path/to/executable/C/program
sh -c "xterm -e ./Cprogram" &
exit
```

When I execute the C program with ./MyScript.sh, the bash window pops up and the C program runs.

Cron won't run the script. The Daemon is running and cron is executing, as I see in /var/log/syslog
I overviewed all priviliges and I do everything as root.

I'd be very happy for any advice. Thanks in advance, JS

Comment: You should run the program without xterm. The terminal is meant for interactive, whereas a cron job always runs in the background.

Comment: Hello Matt Shin, Thank you so much. Everything is working fine now!